# Old line came back at some point from git - no idea why and how to prevent it

Tags: git

I have an issue, that due to it's sensitive nature, I cannot fully give you access to. However, I hope my description will be sufficient to solve this mystery, as it keeps happening.

We use git with a development team of 5 developers. Usually, We use separate branches, that at this point we merge into master, but on this time, we both made the changes directly into master, at least as far as I know.
We had a line in a file, called config.php that had the line:

`define('PP_SANDBOX', true);`

At some point in time, I changed it to

`define('PP_SANDBOX', false);`

However one member of our team, merged his master into origin master. This commit had no changes config.php. The "Merge branch 'master' " commit afterwards also didn't contain any changes to config.php. However The line went back to

`define('PP_SANDBOX', true);`

I used "blame" to get where the error went into the code, but it points to original commit I made, where I added this line (`define('PP_SANDBOX', true);`) at first

I used bisect to get where the error went into the code, but this did nothing to help. The commit where the line went back to the old line, and the "merge" commit, contained no changes to the "config.php" (while it obviously did change). This is not the first time errors like that creep into our code. Just the first time, I can pin it to a specific line change, and locate the commit that created it.

How can I avoid introducing old lines into the code, or for the very least, locate this kind of error, when it's introduced. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you still see the correct line in the history before the merge? What are the parent commits of the merge commit?

Comment: "At some point in time, I changed it to `define('PP_SANDBOX', false);`"—did you commit this change? It's going to be very hard to help you without a clearer picture of what's happening. You don't need to share your sensitive code, but if you can replicate the issue and give us a [mcve] that will go a long way towards figuring out what happened.

Comment: All changes were commited. I'll say more: the change was on the master branch for 13 commits, before it got overriden. However, the commit that bought back the unwanted line, was the first commit by the developer pushed into origin.

Comment: @choroba, the answer is definatly yes. The right commit have stayed for 13 commits by various developers, before rolling back to the old line

Comment: Do you still see the commit that changed it from 'true' to 'false' in the history? Did the rolling back commit was forced pushed to master?

Comment: @mgershen At the point I saw the error, I created a new commit, with PP_SANDBOX changed back to false.
I'm not sure about what you asked. I looked into the diff of all commits, and non of them contained going from false back to true. However, there is list of commits to the master, and I can say that commit "82fcc9f8350" has the property set to false, and right after it, commit "fecc11e2b4d" had it set to true. However when I look into the commit (using bitbucket). However git diff-tree fecc11e2b4d, does not show that a change was applied to config.php

Comment: @GuruYaya It is really hard to guess what happened without the log. But if the other guy isn't force pushing maybe he is working with creating commits without pushing that to the branch while pulling code and resolving conflicts with merge strategy.

If he uses `git pull` and not `git pull --rebase` that might be related (if I understood what you are saying)

Comment: @mgershen I don't think I use git pull --rebase. As for the other guys on my team - most of them just use sourcetree to pull from origin. I have no idea whats the default behaviour of sourcetree on this issue